# Inheriting style from parent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I am trying to add hovering to links, with a class called `<HoverLink />`

Like so:

```
import { Hoverable } from 'react-native-web-hooks';

class HoverLink extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Hoverable >
                {isHovered => (
                    <View accessible style={{ backgroundColor: isHovered ? '#333' : '#fff' }}>
                        <Link {...this.props} >{this.props.children}</Link>
                    </View>
                )}
            </Hoverable>
        )
    }
}
```

And this is how I am using it:

```
<HoverLink style={WebPseudoStyles.footerLinks} target="_blank" src="https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Main_Page">Chinese Grammar Wiki</HoverLink>
```

However when I try to pass in my styles, I get the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.
```

How do I use styles passed in from a parent/HOC? I'm looking around for if there is a way to do this, and I am not seeing anything specific.

And WebPseudoStyles:

```
export const WebPseudoStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    footerLinks: {
        color: footerTextColor,
        textDecoration: "none",
        fontFamily: fontFamily,
        marginBottom: 15
    },
    socialIcons: {
        textDecoration: "none",
        fontFamily: fontFamily,
    },
    socialIconsContainer: {
        backgroundColor: "#1e2234",
        paddingLeft: 10,
        paddingRight: 10, paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginRight: 10,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }
});
```

EDIT:

When viewing the props, it appears that style just becomes a pointer:

```
children: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, type: ƒ, …}
src: "https://www.instagram.com/myinstagram"
style: 134
target: "_blank"
```

Comment: you can pass style from props and define that style in parent component.

Comment: @ShanAlam I gave an example of how I am using it that is causing the error, can you clarify what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The style should be in {...this.props} should it not?

Comment: `WebPseudoStyles.footerLinks` is a valid styles object, right?

Comment: @wentjun Correct

Answer (score 0):

I just converted my styles from a StyleSheet object, to a plain JSON object.

```
export const WebPseudoStyles = {
    footerLinks: {
        color: footerTextColor,
        textDecoration: "none",
        fontFamily: fontFamily,
        marginBottom: 15
    },
    socialIcons: {
        textDecoration: "none",
        fontFamily: fontFamily,
    },
    socialIconsContainer: {
        backgroundColor: "#1e2234",
        paddingLeft: 10,
        paddingRight: 10,
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginRight: 10,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }
};
```

After this, it stopped being a pointer, and instead was the actual object.

Maybe it's not "React-ish", but it worked for now.